# Seeking Title/Author of Post-Apocalyptic Novel Involving Vampires

Tags: story-identification, vampire

I want to read some of the work written by one of the tutors on my writing course but I don't know the title to any of his books and have heard rumours that he writes under a pseudonym. Today in class he told us that in one of the books he'd written a group of vampires get hold, or attempt to get hold, of nukes and use them to create a nuclear winter so they can walk around 24/7 without fear of the sun. Without anything more specific to go on Google hasn't been much help and I can't find any clues anywhere else. My tutor's name is John Sayle if that helps at all.

Comment: I don't know whether they have anything to do with one another, but I did run into a John Sayle who was a writer for [Count Duckula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Count_Duckula), which is fantastic...

Comment: This sounds very like the novel [The Night Eternal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Night_Eternal) though that's by Guillermo del Toro and Chuck Hogan, neither of which seem likely pen names for your instructor :-)

Comment: Is there a reason you can't ask your tutor the author directly?

Answer (score 4):

That description fits the plot of the 1998 Channel 4 series, [Ultraviolet](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0169501/).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraviolet_(TV_serial)):

> The final episode reveals that the vampires' plan does not involve
>   enslaving humanity as suspected. Instead, they plan to cause a nuclear
>   winter, providing long-lasting darkness, and completely wiping out the
>   threat of humanity with an engineered plague. Scientific advances made
>   during their experiments will allow them to survive on synthetic blood
>   and reproduce via live birth, eliminating the need for human victims.

The writing is credited to [Joe Ahearne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_Ahearne)

[image: Joe Ahearne]

[Interview with Joe Ahearne](http://web.archive.org/web/20110120072136/http://www.world-productions.com/wp/content/shows/other/uv/intview1.htm)

Answer (score 3):

The details don't line up exactly with those posted in the question, but *[Vampire Winter](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2357791.Vampire_Winter)* by Lois Tilton may be the answer. In it, nukes are dropped and a nuclear winter, or eternal twilight, allows the protagonist, a vampire (as well as other vampires) to roam about 24/7 in the post apocalyptic world after the war.

[image: pic]